# Sorting the contents of nested list in SQLAlchemy with Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Overview:

I am querying a database using SQLAlchemy. The database contains a list of User objects each with a list of "history" objects. I want to sort the list of histories into order by date.

Query looks like this:

```
history = session.query(
            User.history
        ).limit(100)
```

This returns me a list of lists of history objects, looking like the following:

```
[ 
    [{Title: "N", Date: 2014-05-01T07:00:00-00:00}, {Title:"A", Date: 2017-05-01T07:00:00-00:00}], 
    [{h},{h}], 
    [{h},{h},{h}] 
]
```

The h's are just stand in's for more history dictionaries of the format {Title: "X", Date: 2014-05-01T07:00:00-00:00}

I want to order the contents of each of these subsequences in descending order by date. The input is the object described above and the output is a list of lists containing the history objects ordered by date.

Is there any way to do this at the query level?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How exactly is `User` and esp. `User.history` defined. Your results are not valid Python dictionaries, unless `Title` is a name for an object used as key.